# LWC: How do I show the loading pictures before the component is ready to show?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have plenty custom LWC components, to enhence the using quality, I want to show the loading pictures just like standard components like this:
[image]

I know the spinner, but I rather to use the pics, is it possible? Any available api?

Comment: Do you want to show as above or any pic? If you want pic just take any gif and import that in static resource and then you can load that.

Comment: as above, exact the same.

Comment: That has some logic behind that, not a simple pic. Basically when the UI loads you can have your own div which shows the rolling thing and then hide that when the data is visible in your UI. Like in `template if` tags. Also you might need to do this for each of your `div` tags.

Comment: I would like to use the template if to control the before-loaded and loaded status, and toggle that in the lightning-edit-form's onload method(for example), what I want to know is that is there any way to use the same loading-picture as standard system behavior

Comment: That is not a picture, that is controlled by class `force-placeholder2_detail`. You will have to debug the standard page and get all the details.

Comment: OK, I noticed that, in addition(a stupid tech-question acually), how do you stop the page from rendering, and stop at that exact moment to see the details in debug mode? I tried to see all the classes and structures but it only shows seconds and rerendered by the loaded contents

Comment: Create a custom component and in the doinit write `debugger;` and then proceed.

Comment: Thank you I will try it, nice of you.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question but just to show how to debug the standard page and get the class details :

Create a custom component, put that on page and then inspect element.

Then keep a debugger as shown below, and reload the page.

[image]

Then press `Ctrl + shift + c`  then place your cursor on the field and you will get class details.

[image]